# Finding local maximum of f(m,n)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

Let $ n,m \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } m \geq n \gt 1$

Let $ f(n,m) = \frac{m-n+1}{2(n-1)}$ and therefor:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial m}(m,n) = \frac{1}{2(n-1)}$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(m,n) = -\frac{m}{2(n-1)²}$

Since the two partial derivatives do not have a solution such that they both equal to zero, how can I get the local maximum? Is there a problem in my reasoning?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which reasoning?

Comment: Is it even possible in this situation to find a local maximum, or it is not defined?

Comment: Why not? The sequence $\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has an absolute maximum at $3$, although $x^{1/x}$ has non-zero derivative at $3$.

Comment: But how would one calculate such a maximum in that case?

Comment: For $m=0$ it is a constant $-1/2$; Further differentiation determines if it is maximum, minimum etc.

Comment: It follows easily from the fact that $x^{1/x}$ increases in $(0,e)$ and decreases in $(e,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is discrete, then you have to define the notion of "local." One way to think of it is the $8$ lattice points/neighbors that surround the given point $(m,n)$ and then you can say $(m,n)$ is a local maximum if it's greater than or equal to those $8$ values $f$ is evaluated at. But that would not work because incrementing $m$ by $1$ will always increase your function.

More generally, there is no such notion even if you extend the immediate neighborhood to a greater a raduis because $f$ is strictly increasing in $m:$
$$f(m+1,n) - f(m,n) = \dfrac{1}{2(n-1)} > 0.$$

As a last resort, it *might* be possible to define some weird, discrete topology for which a neighborhood of $m$ does not include $m+1,$ but I am not aware of such things.

Comment: Yes I guess I meant more like a global limit. The thing is I can think that it is certainly n = 2 and m = +inf, just dont really see how to formally prove it, considering all the caveats